# ASP.net binding expression giving object required error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, binding, expression

I am coding a page that use RadAjax tools for ASP.net, now I am using RadAjax panel to update a portion of page but the problem is my page also contains ASP.net binding expressions like <%= textBox.ClientID %> due to these I get an error that cannot update components with <% %> so I searched google and found that this <%= %> can be replaced with this <%# %> to stop this error but now the problem is whenever the new binding statements are called I get a javascript error saying object required like on this expression.

(<%# textBox.ClientID %>).value

where textBox is standard ASP.net control.

Any ideas how can I fix this error. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the content of the <%# textBox.ClientID %> to see what comes up ?

Comment: it gives blank single qoutes '' like these.

Comment: Sorry for late reply Bobby, and yes removing the ajax panel from code makes it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use <%# %> you have to databind the page (or the control). Try to call DataBind in Page_Load and see whether that fixes your problem.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate Slfan, What should I databind in PageLoad event ?

Comment: @Ahmed: I added a code sample. And check the generated HTML. If it still containes your script code (<%# %>), your binding is not correct.